# how to handle this: Get all rows with the same email address, operate on ids, email them once

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, email

Honestly, I do not even know how to ask this question since I also do not have any plan on where to start.

Say I have the following in mySQL:

```
id | URL        | email   |
---|------------|---------|
1  | google.com | a@a.com |
2  | bing.com   | a@a.com |
3  | yahoo.com  | b@a.com |
```

My original plan is:

do something on each URL (analyze it), afterwards send an email corresponding to such URL.
that makes:

1. analyze URL 1, send an email to a@a.com
2. analyze URL 2, send an email to a@a.com
3. analyze URL 3, send an email to b@a.com

why should I still do such spamming act when, I can just send an email to a@a.com will all the analysis.

I am trying to be less-spammer as possible, that is instead of , my refined plan then is:

1. SELECT email FROM table
   --> a@a.com, a@a.com, b@a.com
2. Trim the output such that there will not be duplicate email address
   --> a@a.com, b@a.com
3. Put them in an array or itenary
4. For each element in array SELECT * FROM table WHERE array()
5. For each output(the elements), do the analysis
6. Put the analysis in an array
7. So say, all analysis is complete
8. Email the analysis to the parent email.

Am I doing it right?

Is my plan efficient?

Not memory consuming?

Any better plan to handle this?

Comment: What are you trying to do, the purpose I mean?

Comment: @AliGajani Instead of sending an email each time a URL was analyzed. I want to hold "that" analysis since the email address has multiple URL entries in the database. After all URL were analyzed under the email address, that is the only time I am going to order an sendmail. I think that is just cleaner???

Comment: You could `ORDER BY email, URL ASC` and then build the email over each entry, then only shoot off the email when the next entry has a different email address?

Comment: Memory consumption shouldn't be your main concern, unless you have thousands of emails with thousands of urls, in which case you should make batches. Memory is cheap and PHP is smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch all, group by mail, send later. Useful to separate logics.

```
// Fetch all
$users = $db->fetch('SELECT * FROM table');

// Group by mail
$mails = array();
forach ( $users as $user ) {
  $mail = ... analyze stuff with $user->url
  $mails[$user->mail][] = $mail;
}

// Send
foreach ( $mails as $address => $content ) {
  $subject = count($content) . ' urls analyzed';
  $body = implode("\n\n", $content);
  mail($address, $subject, $body);
}
```

Explanation:

The `->` are how you pick a property of an object. Most database classes return rows as objects, not associative arrays. (I think most, maybe not.) So if `$users` is an array of objects, `$user` will be an object and its mail would be in `$user->mail`. If they're assoc arrays, `$user` will be an array and its mail will be in `$user['mail']`. Both have their advantages.

The 'group by mail' part creates many arrays in `$mails`, grouped by `mail`. The fetch order (from the db) doesn't matter, because PHP stacks the results per `mail`, so `$mails` would be something like:

```
array(
  'a@a.com' => array(
    0 => 'Analytics stuff here...',
    1 => 'Analytics stuff here...',
  ),
  'b@a.com' => array(
    0 => 'Analytics stuff here...',
  ),
)
```

and that's a very neat, compact array with everything you need to send mail. And you could pass it onto another layer of your app. The mail-send-layer, or the html-template-layer, or whatever.

Comment: I think this is the efficient answer I want, but my lil knowledge about PHP gives me hard time to fully understand the code you posted. Would be great if you can elaborate the "group mail code". Btw, what does "->" does? Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER BY` to have the entries grouped by emails like so

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY email
```

Then inside of each entry loop

```
$currEmail = $row['email'];
if ($prevEmail != $currEmail) {
    // send $mail to $prevMail
    $mail = ''; // reset the contents of the e-mail to nothing
}
$mail .= '
    // analysis of whatever you are doing
';
$prevEmail = $currEmail;
```

Don't forget to send the contents of `$mail` after the loop finishes as well! Since the mail sending condition is triggered on the *next row*, the loop will finish with a non-empty `$mail` every time.

This fetches everything with just one query, allows you to "build" your analysis without spamming the same e-mail address with each analysis item, and saves memory, database queries, and processing time by not using arrays or multiple queries.

Comment: I love the simplicity, but you think this is the least-memory-consuming code for this? ... hmm... But yeah, this is what I want afterall. Just that I have hundred different email addresses and a dozen URL under each email address.

Comment: @user1824371 memory isn't that big of a concern unless you're dealing with thousands of email addresses